# How to obtain the object of a custom added row in kendo grid?

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am adding a new row in kendo grid when a button is clicked like this:

```
 $('#btn_addUser').click(function () {
        document.getElementById('btn_save').style.visibility = "visible";
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').addRow();
        $(".k-grid-edit-row").appendTo("#grid tbody");
    });
```

Then i declared another button.When this button is clicked, I want the row object of the new row which has got added by the click of above defined button so that I can access the values typed in the fields of the newly created row.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you are asking for, but this may help: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

Comment: thanks for reply.I have checked the above link already and could not find the requirement that i wanted.

Comment: Several of questions: which insertion mode are you using (inline, incell or popup)?; if you want to insert a row with a specific content why do create the object and then insert it into the DataSource; for inserting the cell at the bottom of your grid `$(".k-grid-edit-row").appendTo("#grid tbody");` is not ideal since it break styling.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai. I think I figured it out my orginal problem. And it would be greatful if you could point me what to use instead of $(".k-grid-edit-row").appendTo("#grid tbody"); that doesn't break styling and add a new row as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gave me the grid object:-

```
 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

Using this I could access the newly added row as grid._data[0].Name,grid._data[0].Role.roleId etc.. (: